# Selenium / Python How to switch browser session to new page and select new page elements

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a web scraper using Selenium and Python. Here is an example where I'm using for google search. Once I programmatically enter the search text and click enter, browser correctly goes to the second page. How can I grab different elements on this new page? I believe I have to switch to a new session but I'm not sure how to.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Desktop/projects/chromedriver")
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')

elem.send_keys('stackoverflow' + Keys.RETURN)
```

Now I am on the next page showing result for the search I made. I want to select the element from this page:

```
new_page = browser.get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(new_page)
```

I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

How can I switch to new page to grab its elements?

Comment: Can you post all the code? you must have accidentally redefined the `browser` variable somewhere, likely to the result of some function call.

Comment: Hi this is complete code. I just do not how to switch selenium to grab new page so that I can select elements from it.

Comment: you don't need to manually reload a page in selenium, the driver (`browser`) in your case will always reflect the current page. The `browser.page_source` would have the new page source after you `send_keys`.

Comment: if you `print(type(browser))` after your `elem.send_keys`, what do you see?

Comment: Brilliant, you are right. Browser always tracks the current page.